# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.bottary.Movie

Tags: java, android

i tried to show the image and textview in recyclerview but i can't find the problem , i put the photo and the text in firebase in "" what is the problem ?

> Java

```
    MoviesRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false));
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Movie> first_tMovie = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Movie p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Movie.class);
                first_tMovie.add(p);
            }
            MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(HomeActivity.this,first_tMovie);
            MoviesRv.setAdapter(movieAdapter)
```

there is the model class

> Java

```
public class Movie {
private String title;
private String description;
private int thumbnail;
private String studio;
private String Rating;
private String streaminglink;

public Movie(String title , int thumbnail) {
    this.title = title;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;

}

public Movie(String title, int thumbnail) {
    this.title = title;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}



public int getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you can't pass an argument of Movie.class into the value argument:

Instead change this:

```
  Movie p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Movie.class);
```

to this:

```
Movie p = (Movie)dataSnapshot1.getValue();
```

or pass the argument correctly i.e

```
Movie p = new Movie(datasnapshot1.child("x").getValue(),datasnapshot1.child("thumbnail").getValue());
```

Comment: still the same bro the app crash and here is the image from firebase (https://ibb.co/Bj4kzwT) ==>     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.bottary.Movie

Comment: when you click on the line in your Log what particular line of code is giving you issues?  If you're trying to store a Firebase Storage object then best thing is to get it's download URL and store it in the Movie.class...then use something like Glide to load the image in your Adapter class

Comment: i already did it i load my images in picasso library there is my adapter class https://ibb.co/6R20xGY

Comment: Can you give me the LogCat of the error it's coming up with? Also there should be a highlighted area within that error, click on the top highlighted area which should take you to the exact line causing the error...let me know what that is?